# Design workflow in celery using chain and group

Tags: python, celery, workflow, chain

I am new in celery and I am trying to design a workflow in celery using Chain, Groups and Chord. Here is what I have done so far:

```
def __chainfileprocessing(config):
    filelist, src = get_files_for_processing(config)
    for fileattr in filelist:
        chain(  download_file.s(fileattr, src)
                ,importdata.s(fileattr, src)
                ,post_processing.s(fileattr, src)
             ).apply_async()
```

**Current execution order:**

- All the download_file() tasks are getting executed
- Then all import_data() tasks are getting excuted
- Then all post_processing() task are getting executed

**What I need:**

Task should get executed in `download_file() => import_data() =>  post_processing()` order for each item in filelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing what you said you want. The `chain` will start tasks for `download_file`, then `import_date`, then `post_processing`, in that order, for each item in filelist.

What your code does is:

- start a chain of tasks (`download_file`, then `importdata`, then `post_processing`) for file A asynchronously; this starts `download_file` for file A. When that completes, it will start the `importdata` task for file A. The `apply_async` returns immediately; it doesn't wait for any of the tasks to complete.
- start a chain of tasks (`download_file`, then `importdata`, then `post_processing`) for file B asynchronously; this starts `download_file` for file B. When that completes, it will start the `importdata` task for file B. The `download_file` task for file A is likely running, but this call doesn't know that; it just adds a task to the queue.
- etc

At the end of the loop, what you've sent to celery is `download_file` for files A...n. As each `download_file` task completes, it will submit the next task in its chain.

There are no dependencies between the tasks for different files; from the code you've posted, it doesn't look there needs to be (why should file 2 have to wait for file 1 to complete?)

Comment: So according to you, code is executing is same manner which i am expeting ? or do i need to make any changes ?

Comment: Yes, it is doing what you expect in that importdata will be started after download_file, and post_processing after that, for each file.

Comment: Can you suggest me how i can do exception handling here? If download_file method throws error next fuction should not get called.

Comment: The Celery docs on `chain` https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.0/userguide/canvas.html#chains say "You can also add error callbacks using the on_error method"